# Is it possible to get a variable from another class with a string?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, class, variables

What i mean with my question is can you get a variable from another class using a string instead of the variable name?

Example:

```
var varName:String = "stageHeight";
trace(stage."" + varName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square bracket notation:

```
var varName:String = "stageHeight";
trace(stage[varName]);
```

Which can be chained like so:

```
object["prop1"]["prop2"]["etc"]
```

Comment: Damn spellcheck on a phone makes it painful to write code.